# Неверное отображение русских символов в консоли VS Code при использовании Fira Code

Tags: шрифты, visual-studio-code

Использую редактор VS Code.

Семейство шрифтов: Fira Code

Кодировку пробовал разную (utf8, utf8bom, utf16le, utf16be, windows1252)

При использовании кода:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int[] num = new int[5];

      try {
         for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
         num[i] = i;
         System.out.print(num[i] + " ");
         }
      }        
      catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
      System.out.println("\nВнутри обработчика Catch");
      }
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Arfer catch processor");
}
```

получаю вывод в консоль:

```
0 1 2 3 4
Внутри обработчика Catch
�чика Catch
ch
Arfer catch processor
```

Вопрос состоит в том, можно ли, оставив Fira Code, исправить вывод строк, содержащие русские символы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В settings.json добавьте строчку:

```
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Consolas"
```

Comment: Это не очень-то согласуется с последним предложением вопроса.

Comment: @insolor возможно вы правы, я подумал что Fira Code нужно оставить в редакторе, а в консоли иметь другой тип шрифта.